# How to do bindingRedirect for DLL project to prevent - warning MSB3247: Found conflicts

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DLL project which is called "Foo" and is referencing Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.7. 
And i have a second DLL project which is called "Bar", references "Foo" and is referencing Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.5. And because of various reasons, its not possible to change the Newtonsoft.Json version of both.

When I am compile this, I get this warning on project "Bar":

> warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

So I've created a app.config in project "Bar":

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0-4.0.7" newVersion="4.0.5"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

But the did not prevent the warning.

The interesting point now is, when I change the "Bar" project from DLL to Console, the warning disappears. So i guess the redirect only works for executables.

How can I get rid of that warning in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want access different NewtonSoft.Json dll versions? Not? Remove the  block from configs and everything works fine.

Comment: As I said, "Bar" requires 4.0.5 and "Foo" requires 4.0.7. "Foo" is an external so i can not change its binding. "Bar" references RavenDB which requires 4.0.5 to work. And the config block dose not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

there may be different occasions for this error,
I recieved the message MSB3247 and solved the problem be reloading a excluded DLL-Project to my solution. The project had a reference to the excluded DLL, but there are former compiled versions of the DLL, maybe that caused the problem - anyway now it works again (-:
I hope it helps